# Oracle Apex: Hide Interactive Report Control Panel

Tags: css, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have an Interactive Report with multiple saved reports.  For the Primary Report, I want to hide the information bar that indicates highlight filter "Errors Found" is active,  as it just takes up space, and the users would not need to disable it:

[image: Sample IR Report]

I used the debugger to get the div class and ID, but I don't know where I can put the CSS to set that ID to hidden; here is the div and ID, and the `display: none` code I inserted via the debugger to hide that area:

[image: Sample CSS]

So I want to add to that division/id

```
style="display: none;"
```

I don't know how/where to put that code in my page definition to hide that division/ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use the class in that div to do this, like

```
.a-MediaBlock.a-IRR-controlsContainer.a-Collapsible.is-collapsed {
display: none !important;
}
```

I think ID can change in a update of the application, but you can use id too:

```
div#R91.._control_panel {
display: none !important;
}
```

put this code in page properties --> css inline.
[image]

Comment: Works great!  Both methods worked; thanks for the warning that the ID could change...